# How to use two different UI (CSS) frameworks, one mobile, other desktop, in the same Angular project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, ionic4

I have to create mobile and desktop versions of the same webapp. For two use cases I have chosen two different CSS frameworks. In my case it is ionic4 and bootstrap.
Everything else in the app is the same. It is based on Ngrx store, uses the same API service (provider) etc.

So my question is specifically - is there a way to have the same project (in the IDE sense, like WebStorm) and same Git repository for both. How to configure such a project file tree? What should be done to the build scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Angular CLI supports multiple apps/libs in workspace. Please check https://angular.io/guide/file-structure

Answer (score 0):

Use angular CLI. You can use it.